# How to run Dockerfile at Silicon Mac M1 from Intel Mac

Tags: macos, docker, dockerfile, apple-silicon

I'm not a native speaker of English, but I want to ask a question on Stack Overflow.
and I am a beginner at Docker.

I am trying to set up the development environment at Silicon Mac M1 from Intel mac.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
. ./env.list
# Build Docker image
# docker pull store/ibmcorp/db2_developer_c:11.1.4.4-x86_64
docker build -t ${REPOSITORY}:${TAG} .

# DOCKERFILE
FROM store/ibmcorp/db2_developer_c:11.1.4.4-x86_64
RUN yum -y update && yum clean all
RUN curl ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/vault.centos.org/7.8.2003/os/x86_64/Packages/glibc-common-2.17-307.el7.1.x86_64.rpm > /tmp/glibc-common.rpm
RUN rm -f /etc/localtime
RUN mkdir /var/custom
```

and I got errors like below

```
Step 2/30 : RUN yum -y update && yum clean all
 ---> [Warning] The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
```

I already add `--platform linux/amd64` another docker run command

```
#!/bin/bash
. ./env.list
docker rm -f api-db
docker run --name api-db -h db2server --restart=always --detach --privileged=true -p 50000:50000 -p 55000:55000 --platform linux/amd64 --env-file env.list sample-app:v1.0
```

what should I do for a dockerfile?

Thank you so much for reading.

Have a good day! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple M1 is `arm64v8` instruction set processor, so you can not run `amd64` (`X86_64`) on it without emulation. In general, Docker has the ability to emulate other architectures if the emulation based on `bitfmt` is set up (and on maxOS with intel CPU it's already set-up), however the emulation for `amd64` on M1 is not stable yet. This means that for some period of time you will be restricted to 'arm64' images.

To fetch the proper image for you architecture during the build you need to add the following.

```
FROM --platform linux/arm64 <image name>
```

You need to check if there are images for `db2` development environment for arm by doing

```
docker pull --platform linux/arm64 store/ibmcorp/db2_developer_c
```

Comment: the correct syntax: `FROM --platform=linux/arm64 <image name>` (requires equal sign)

Comment: MacOs Monterey 12.2.1 worked
`FROM --platform=linux/x86_64 <image name>`